# Edge detection and histogram matching of two images using open CV python.

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, python-idle

I need to find edge detection of medical  images using OpenCV python .Which edge detector will be the best suited for my work? I have tried using canny Edge detector. I want to find edges of the medical images and find the histogram matching between two images. 
Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: I did not downvote, but per the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."  Requesting an algorithm probably falls along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the images you're working on ? That will be better.

Also, you can try this code. It allows you to change the parameters of canny filters, Thresold 1 and thresold 2 and hence you will get an overall idea how you can apply canny filter to the image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

#image window
cv2.namedWindow('image')

#loading images
img = cv2.imread('leo-messi-pic.jpg',0)     # load your image with proper path

# create trackbars for color change
cv2.createTrackbar('th1','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('th2','image',0,255,nothing)

while(1):
    # get current positions of four trackbars
    th1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('th1','image')
    th2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('th2','image')
    #apply canny 
    edges = cv2.Canny(img,th1,th2)
    #show the image
    cv2.imshow('image',edges)
    #press ESC to stop
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As far as, histogram comparison is concerned. You can find all the histogram related cv2 APIs  here.

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html

Hope it helps.